# Python: Error tokenizing data. C error: Calling read(nbytes) on source failed with input nzip file

Tags: python, pandas

I am using `conda` `python` `2.7`

```
python --version
Python 2.7.12 :: Anaconda 2.4.1 (x86_64)
```

I have fallowing method to read large gzip files:

```
df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(filePath, fileName),
     sep='|', compression = 'gzip', dtype='unicode', error_bad_lines=False)
```

but when I read the file I get the following error:

```
pandas.parser.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Calling read(nbytes) on source failed. Try engine='python'.
Segmentation fault: 11
```

I read all the existing answers but most of those questions had errors such as additional columns. I was already handling that with `error_bad_lines=False` option.

What are my options here?

Found something interesting when I tried to uncompress the file:

```
gunzip -k myfile.txt.gz 
gunzip: myfile.txt.gz: unexpected end of file
gunzip: myfile.txt.gz: uncompress failed
```

Comment: No way we can know with out the data file or sample data.

Comment: Have you tried using the Python engine option for reading your data, as suggested by the error message?

Comment: Have you tried to add `engine='python'` as the error message suggests?

Comment: PS: pandas version?

Comment: @Boud `pandas                    0.17.1              np110py27_0 ` that what conda gives also tried the engine no effect

Comment: It s worth a try with the latest pandas version, even temporarily so that you can see if a old bug is fixed in the latest version. Also could it be possible the zipped file is corrupted? Unzip the csv and try to parse it directly

Comment: @Boud Any chance I could catch the line that probably causing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I didn't really find a python solution but using `unix` tools I manage to find a solution:

First I use `zless myfile.txt.gz > uncompressedMyfile.txt`
then I use `sed` tool to remove the last line because I clearly saw that last line was corrupt.

`sed '$d' uncompressedMyfile.txt`

I gzipped the file again `gzip -k uncompressedMyfile.txt`

I was able to successfully read the file with following python code:

```
try:
    df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(filePath, fileName),
                        sep='|', compression = 'gzip', dtype='unicode', error_bad_lines=False)
except CParserError:
    print "Something wrong the file"
return df
```

Answer (score 19):

Chances are the path you put is actually that of a `folder` instead of the `file` that needs to be read.

`Pandas.read_csv` can't read folders and need explicit compatible file names.

Comment: In my case, The folder had the same name as the file. home/file.csv/file.csv xDD

Comment: bruhhhhhhhhhhhhh

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes the error shows up if you have the file already open. Try closing the file and re-running

Answer (score 2):

The input zip file is corrupted. Get a proper copy of this file from the source of try to use zip repairing tools before you pass it along to pandas.

Answer (score 0):

This error also occurs when trying to load in files from oneDrive, and you are not login or its not running on your pc.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error when I did not have enough memory to read a file. So in my case, the solution is turning off the programs that are taking up a lot of memory. As I use Windows, I check Task Manager to get this info.

Comment: This answer should most likely have been a Comment on the post rather than left as an answer

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35075971)

Comment: Thanks, I added a solution in my case.